# How to save multiple image names into database by using dropzone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone to upload the images. image will be uploaded to server folder while image name will be saved in database table.

here is my code :

public class FormUploader_dz : IHttpHandler
{

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/");
    string[] files;
    int numFiles;
    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
    numFiles = files.Length;
    numFiles = numFiles + 1;

    string str_image = "";

    foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
        //  int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);


            str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
            string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/") + str_image;
            file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);

            Service.SaveImage(strFileName, context.Session["Id"].ToString());

        }
    }
    context.Response.Write(str_image);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Service file code : which will insert image name into table.

```
public static void SaveImage(string strImage, string Id)
{
    string strSql = @"update tablename set image=@image where id=@Id

    ";
    SqlParameter[] objSqlParameter ={
                                       new SqlParameter("@image",strImage),
                                       new SqlParameter("@Id",Id)
                                   };
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(strConnectionString, CommandType.Text, strSql, objSqlParameter);
}
```

Now here problem is i have 4 columns in table to save 4 different image name. what i am actually doing is allowing user to upload max 4 images. i have 4 columns as img1, img2, img3, img4.

here how to insert/update image name into table, as their are 4 diffrent columns for images!
here if user wants he can upload 4 images. so how to decide that in which column the image name will go?????

any suggestions??????

Comment: does it matter which column? if not you can just do it in order like a loop and increment by 1 each time.

Comment: column name doesn't matter!

Comment: here problem is if user uploads 4 images at a time. how will i write query n code to upload those 4 images?

string strSql = @"update tablename set image=@image where id=@Id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact syntax but something like this could work.

```js
// **********************************
int counter = 0; // set up the counter
// **********************************

 foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
    {
  
  
        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
        //  int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
        
   // **********************************
   counter++; // increment the counter
      // **********************************
   
            fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);


            str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
            string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/") + str_image;
            file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
            
// **********************************
            Service.SaveImage(strFileName, context.Session["Id"].ToString(), counter); // add counter variable to the path.
// **********************************

        }
    }
 

// **********************************
// add a column variable and then add it to your column name. like string columnName = "img+columnCount"
// **********************************
public static void SaveImage(string strImage, string Id, int columnCount)
{
    // **********************************
    string strSql = @"update tablename set img@columnName=@image where id=@Id";
    // **********************************
    
    SqlParameter[] objSqlParameter ={
                                       new SqlParameter("@strImage",strImage),
                                       new SqlParameter("@Id",Id)
                                   };
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(strConnectionString, CommandType.Text, strSql, objSqlParameter);
}
```

Comment: string strSql = @"update tablename set img@columnName=@image where id=@Id";

how will this line decide the column names in which image to be inserted????  columns :  img1, img2, img3, img4??

Comment: img@columnName=@image where img is the column name plus the variable columnName

Comment: String column = "img"+columnName which would be an integer from your loop above passed into the function. If you set the max uploads to 4 it will go in order from 1 => 4. So the function will run four times, incrementing the counter and thus the column name. img1, img2, img3, img4